# Javascript not working after putting radio buttons in an index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, radio-button

I have an array of rows, each with a radio button with the same name (name='status'). I have put the radio buttons into an index so that each radio button will reflect its correct value.  However, the javascript no longer works to change the value - I am stumped with the corresponding changes I need to make to the javascript.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->form_action; ?>" method="post">
    <p class="hide"><input name="status" type="text" value="" /></p>
    <table id="manage-items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->translate('Item');?></th>
                <th><th><?php echo $this->translate('Status');?></th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php $ind = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) {
                $item_link = 'type=product';
                ?>
                    <tr id="item_<?php echo $ind; ?>">
                        <td data-label="Title"><span class="orangelink"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span></td>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:22px" class="color-status-<?php echo $item['active']; ?>">
                            <?php if (in_array($item['active'], array(0, 1))) { ?>
                                <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]" value="1" <?php if ($item['active'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>>Active
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]" value="0" <?php if ($item['active'] == 0) echo 'checked'; ?>>Inactive
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php echo $item['active']; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php $ind++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //console.log(jQuery)
    head.ready('jquery', function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[name="radio"]').click(function () {
                var status = this.value;
                var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
                console.log('here now')
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "?module=items&controller=block&action=modDaStatusBro",
                    data: 'id=' + id + '&status=' + status,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#' + id).animate({
                            'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
                        }, 400);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == 'ok') {
                            $.get(window.location.href, function (data) {
                                $('#' + id).html($(data).find('#' + id).html());
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $("#" + id + "").animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent'}, 400).find('.tooltip').simpletooltip();
                                    deletePage();
                                }, 500);
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert(result);
                            $("#" + id + "").animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent'}, 400);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code into a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can better debug it.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Just pasted what I have above here: https://jsfiddle.net/7quo5akr/.  Not sure how to link up db in jsfiddle to illustrate the multiple rows.

Comment: The ajax is triggered on a click in the text input, in the above Fiddle. But I'm pretty sure it should be triggered by a click on the radios. Try using `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {` instead of `$('input[name="status"]').click(function () {`

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the generated HTML sent to the client for (say) two rows, and confirm you don't want a separate choice for active/inactive status in each row.

Comment: @Traktor53, I'm not exactly sure how to show you generated HTML for 2 rows in an array without the db, but here is an attempt - https://jsfiddle.net/6hLjr2zy/.  Yes, each row needs to have a separate choice for  active/inactive, which is why I implemented the index - $ind.  The problem I am having in the above (i.e. when the index is an the array) is with integrating the $ind references into the javascript. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What @Traktor53 meant... Is that you could post the "generated HTML" to help us, since we obviously can't use the PHP. **How to do that?** : simple, run your page, hit [F12], click on `<body>` tag, right-click it, in the context menu: click copy > copy element... Then paste it in your question. (Instructions are for Chrome inspector, but I suppose you can find the equivalent in any browser.)

Comment: Tx @Traktor53, I just got to my dev computer and  created the "generated html" but it is VERY long and there's no way to attach here. I'll try your suggestions below and see if I can fix it. Otherwise, i'll look for a way to add a shortened version of the generated html.

Comment: You may wish to check my answer first. I've shown the _two_ lines that were of interest as "expected".  Do not post pages of content, thank you!

Comment: @Traktor53, Above, I made two changes you suggested: 1. I added the wild card in the js. 2. I removed the div.  I then replaced the tr id with the div id. I did not replace (name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]") with (name="item[n][status]") because that resulted in the current values not registering for the radio buttons. My new code did trigger the javascript, so that is progress, but I got the error, "item not found".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Table data elements generated in PHP between

```
 <tr id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
 ....
 </tr>
```

do not appear to contain input elements named "status". The HTML generated for each value of `$ind` is expected to be

```
        <input type="radio" name="item[n][status]"  .... Active
        <input type="radio" name="item[n][status]"  .... Inactive
```

where n is the value of $ind. But the selector in

```
        $('input[name="status"]').click(function () {
```

doesn't match the name format. A one key stroke solution would be to  to add a  [* wild card](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to the selector to match "status" anywhere in the name value:

```
        $('input[name*="status"]').click(function () {
```

Other possibilities exist such as adding a special class name to each radio button affected (not recommended), or add a special data attribute to each radio input to be found by query selector (feasible).

---

Footnote: DIV elements surrounding TR elements should not be there. DIV is not listed as a permitted child element of [TBODY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) elements, nor a permitted  parent object of [TR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) elements.

---

(Answer to comment)

A jQuery plugin is needed for [color animation](https://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/) of properties, e.g. `backgroundColor`.

Code can be downloaded from CDNs at

https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js , or
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.min.js

or the entire package can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

Comment: @ian please post comments on the answer here. Glad you've made progress but it sounds like you have a new question, resulting from solving this one. If you wish to ask about an "item not found" error please include the conditions leading up to it being generated, where it is detected and where it is reported. Provide a minimal test case to verify and reproduce the problem if possible. Unless the PHP code has a problem, please use snippets of HTML sent to the browser instead of PHP source. Good luck.

Comment: Ahhh, you are seriously not understanding the difference between PHP source code processed on the server and HTML output sent from the server to the client.  You did not replace (name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]") with (name="item[n][status]")  because the thing on the left is the PHP which generated the HTML on the right as output, where `n` in `[n]` is not the letter 'n' but the value of `$ind` in the PHP loop.

Comment: Tx @Traktor53, I actually understood the PHP / html output differences, I just didn't understand your description well. Regardless, I got it working and really appreciate the help you provided.  I ended up reverting to one of the other suggestions above, using     $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {   instead of the wild card. I changed my code above. Again, thanks very much for your time!!

Comment: Hi @Traktor53, I do have one more question, if you have a minute. The javascript is mostly working and the ajax is working. BUT, the beforeSend: animation is not working:

function
 ($('#' + id).animate({
     'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
      }, 400);
I've been failing to get the correct references all night. As you can see, I'm still very much learning javascript. Tx for any ideas.